# Why use the binary number 64 in base64 as opposed to whole ASCII set?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, base64, character, ascii

I'm trying to understand why we would use Base64 to convert binary data to ASCII characters rather than just converting it straight to ASCII. In every calculation of Base64 that I've seen, you either start with ASCII characters, or start with binary data which is converted to ASCII in the process of eventually converting it to Base64.

**My question is:** Why not just leave it in ASCII, rather than converting it to the Base64 subset?

I've read through all the related questions on Stackoverflow and while I've found lots of useful info, this is the part of the question that I still can't wrap my head around.

Comment: Please give more context of the programming environment and language you are in. (BTW-ASCII doesn't support all byte values so you must not mean ASCII.)

Comment: This isn't part of a specific project; just theory. With Base64 you express a sequence of binary data using a sequence of text characters from a set of 64 characters. I'm just wondering why we would use 64 characters in particular, rather than use the ASCII set which has 100 and something. I assume it has to do with the fact that 64 is binary, but I don't understand why we need to use a binary number in this scenario.

Comment: Base64 is used when data is moved. Without a transport document or mechanism with certain limitations, you are right, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons. I think the few most important reasons are:

- 64 is a good number, it requires less calculations (in fact just shifts) to convert bytes to base64 and the inverse. No multiplication or divisions. Easy, and fast, especially without putting much more load to mail servers. It is also easy to calculate the required output buffer.
- It was choose to have a safe set. Not all character in ASCII are safe or in ISO. Some countries changes `$` or `&` or `~`. Not all character set have `{`. ASCII changed definition of few chars (e.g. `@` position). Space should be allowed (but outside semantic use), the same with control characters. Do not assume ASCII were available on every computer, or on mail servers. In fact ISO C version 1990 supports machines without all ASCII characters.
- it should not interfere with other delimiters (email headers, URL, etc.), where it was supposed to be used, so no quote characters, not `:`. Unfortunately web use `/` and `=`, but because there were many free characters, it had been simple to solve the problem, without redesigning all.